# ASP.NET application on Windows Server print using client printer

Tags: asp.net, networking, windows-server-2012, zebra-printers, asp.net5

So I have an asp.net 5 MVC 6 application on a windows 2012 R2 and in my code, I send a print request to a Zebra KR403 receipt printer, which works when the application is run locally from my visual studio debugging sessions, but when I run the application from the server, it doesn't recognize the printer and therefore does not send the print request. I turned off the firewalls on the client computer and allowed printer sharing and I am still not able to get it to print.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: There is no error message that I'm getting, the printer is just not being recognized as being there at all and is being bypassed.